# Can we upload a string to s3 from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

The below code is for uploading a file to s3, can we use S3BucketPublisher class to upload a string into s3 ?

```
script.step([$class                              : 'S3BucketPublisher',
                             consoleLogLevel                     : 'WARNING',
                             acl              : 'PublicRead',
                             dontWaitForConcurrentBuildCompletion: false,
                             entries                             : [
                                     [bucket           : fullBucketPath,
                                      flatten          : true,
                                      keepForever      : true,
                                      managedArtifacts : false,
                                      noUploadOnFailure: false,
                                      selectedRegion   : bucketRegion,
                                      sourceFile       : fileName]
                             ],
                             pluginFailureResultConstraint       : 'FAILURE'])
```